# How to check if WPF control is hosted within WinForms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

I have a WPF control which in some cases exists as a component of WPF application and in the other is hosted in Windows Forms. How can I detect the second case (a WPF control is embedded inside WinForms)?

Comment: I'd try ``Window.GetWindow(ctrl);`` and would expect it to return null, in a hosted environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
HwndSource wpfHandle = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
if (wpfHandle != null)
{
    ElementHost host = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromChildHandle(wpfHandle.Handle) as ElementHost;
    if(host != null)
    {
        //hosted in ElementHost...
    }
}
```

Comment: For future readers: `PresentationSource.FromVisual(this)` will only return a correct value if your control has already been loaded. Depending on how you instantiate your control, you might need to perform this after the `Loaded` event has been raised.